# CSV File - Powershell - Converting Duplicates Values to Unique Ids using CountIF

Tags: powershell, automation, hashtable, import-csv

I'm trying to use hash tables to do vlookup within powershell, but there are multiple matches for some of the values and as you know vlookup only matches the first value and then moves on. So I was hoping to get some assistance to accomplish the below to assign a unique id to each record.

Sample Data:

| GroupName | CountIf |
| --- | --- |
| Marvel | 3 |
| Marvel | 3 |
| Marvel | 3 |
| DCU | 4 |
| DCU | 4 |
| DCU | 4 |
| DCU | 4 |
| WB | 5 |
| WB | 5 |
| WB | 5 |
| WB | 5 |
| WB | 5 |

Desired Output:

| GroupName | CountIf | UniqueID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marvel | 3 | Marvel-3 |
| Marvel | 3 | Marvel-2 |
| Marvel | 3 | Marvel-1 |
| DCU | 4 | DCU-4 |
| DCU | 4 | DCU-3 |
| DCU | 4 | DCU-2 |
| DCU | 4 | DCU-1 |
| WB | 5 | WB-5 |
| WB | 5 | WB-4 |
| WB | 5 | WB-3 |
| WB | 5 | WB-2 |
| WB | 5 | WB-1 |

I've tried using ref to append an id to the values, but it doesn't provide me the directed results.

```
uid=0
$filename | Select-Object @{n="UniquidID"; e={$_.GroupName,(([ref]$uid).Value++) -Join "-" }}
```

The above returns UniqueID as below:

| UniqueID |
| --- |
| Marvel-0 |
| Marvel-1 |
| DCU-2 |
| Marvel-3 |
| ........ |

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you provide your sample data as plain text as well as your expected outcome (as plain text too)

Comment: Thanks, I edited and formatted the post. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to loop by `GroupName` and then create a new `UniqueID` property that uses the value of `GroupName` plus an index starting from `1`:

```
Import-Csv path\to\input.csv | Group-Object GroupName | ForEach-Object {
    $idx = @{ i = 1 }
    $_.Group | Select-Object *, @{ N='UniqueID'; E= { '{0}-{1}' -f $_.GroupName, $idx.i++ }}
}
```

Output should look as the one expected, the downside is that `Group-Object` wont preserve the same order as your input but this can be solved by `Sort-Object` if needed.

```
GroupName CountIf UniqueID
--------- ------- --------
DCU       4       DCU-1
DCU       4       DCU-2
DCU       4       DCU-3
DCU       4       DCU-4
Marvel    3       Marvel-1
Marvel    3       Marvel-2
Marvel    3       Marvel-3
WB        5       WB-1
WB        5       WB-2
WB        5       WB-3
WB        5       WB-4
WB        5       WB-5
```